# add dots to list of tables in contents and add contents to contents itself

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, books

I have two question regarding toc in `book` class.

First, I added list of table to contents using:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
```

It appears in contents. However, there is no dots filling the gap between the title and page number. How to add dots for this, please?

Second, how do I add the contents itself to the contents itself, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `tocbibind` package `\usepackage{tocbibind}`. Donts don't appear as toc is put as a chapter. If you need dots then use `tocloft` package.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks for commenting. Could you give a bit more details, please?

Comment: @HarishKumar The `tocbibind` worked. But still not dots. Where and how to use `tocloft`, please?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Comment: I'm still asking myself what can be the reason for listing the table of contents in the table of contents. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I know. It is so strange. But apparently it is common practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding contents in toc, just add `\usepackage{tocbibind}` in your preamble. To put dots for contents, load `tocloft` package and issue `\renewcommand \cftchapdotsep{4.5}`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
 \renewcommand \cftchapdotsep{4.5}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a variant using `titlesec` instead of `fncychap`

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand \cftchapdotsep{4.5}

 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\filcenter\bfseries\Large}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
    {4ex}
    {\titlerule
        \vspace{2ex}%
    }
    [\vspace{2ex}%
        \titlerule] 
    %
    \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
    {\filcenter\bfseries\Large}
    {}
    {4ex}
    {\titlerule
        \vspace{2ex}%
    }
    [\vspace{2ex}%
        \titlerule]
    \titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
    \titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless} {0pt}{15pt}{40pt}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is cool. But it will mess up with my preferred title font as in `\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap};
  \ChNameVar{\centering\Large\bfseries};
  \ChTitleVar{\centering\Large\bfseries}`. Is there a fix to this, please?

Comment: @LaTeXfan Try with `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`. However, it is better not to use `fncychap`, use `titlesec` instead and format the titles.

Comment: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` worked even with `fncychap`. Brilliant! Thank you! How and where did you learn this stuff, please?

Comment: @LaTeXfan: I have added a `titlesec`  variant.